# Audio Stream URLs and Problems Solving Stream URLs

Tags: java, android

I thought I would share what I went through. This is not a question.  We solved a problem.  I’m sure old media server hounds know about this.  I didn’t.  I hope this saves you time in the future.

Problem: My customer’s Shoutcast listing went away but their provider didn’t. (Shoutcast has listings for many stations as a convenience.  My customer’s used to be: 
http: //yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=3012xxx and then it went away!  Their station didn’t.

We were left with several URLs provided us by the station and none of them played via our player.  Within each .pls, .ram file, the same URL was listed (see note) - something like this:

http: //74.53.186.162:9082/

How did we solve the problem?

On the Shoutcast console page above, there is a listen link.  It refers to a URL with a .pls extension.  It also shows the sample rate, number of current listeners, etc.  The URL worked.

What made this interesting is that file located at that URL actually was a .pls text file with the original URL (something like http: //74.53.186.162:9082/) !

What did I learn?

1. Shoutcast servers know what kind of client is accessing their data.  I would assume the same to be true of IceCast servers.  How did I know?  The circular URL reference.  This means that your player parses text files first much like your browser looks at the mime type.
2. Media player classes that you use in code can be really dumb.  They’re sensitive to mime types, bit rates, extension names, etc.
3. If I have the .pls or other media file, I can use them locally.
4. Hard coded IP addresses are just as bad as they ever were.  Unfortunately, developers don’t have much control over this.

Note: Audio Streams with .pls, .ram, etc are text files that have URLs in them to the actual stream.  The text file has other meta data as well.  If you take the raw URL from the txt file and launch it, you might get a Shoutcast Server interface that gives you stream information that your player might use.  (When viewing a radio station’s website, you can sometimes find the stream URL in the player’s launch parms.  Sometimes they can be different.)

Comment: Not a question, should someone close?  Would make a good blog entry though.

Comment: Yep. I just thought I would post it - I don't have a blog this would fit on...

Comment: Can you rephrase this as the problem you were trying to solve and post the solution below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thank you.